# Minimize an integral vs Minimize the argument of a integral.

Tags: integration, optimization

I have some trouble understanding this apparently simple concept.
Let's say we have to do a minimization of an integral and I need to find L* 
$$ L^{*} = \min_{z(x)} \int f(x,z(x)) dx$$

Can I bring the min inside and thus write:

$$ L^{*} = \int \min_{z(x)}  f(x,z(x)) dx$$

If so, why? 
Intuitively make sense, but I can't really see the mathematical reason behind.

Comment: I don't think the notation you use ($\min_{z(x)}$) is self-explanatory.

Comment: z(x) is a function that can have different shapes, all in function of x,  and we need to find the one that minimizes the integral

Comment: @SaucyO'Path the OP's notation is not ideal, but almost certainly they're minimizing over functions $z$ in some function space.

Comment: @user7530 ... and whether or not that space contains the function $x\mapsto\operatorname{argmin}f(x,\bullet)$ is certainly an important part of the question.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path yes, agreed

Answer (score 6):

No, you cannot do this. Let's look at a simpler example, where you're minimizing over a real number rather than a function:

$$\min_a \int_0^1 (x-a)^2\,dx.$$

Here you need to pick a *single value of a* for which the integral is minimized; the best you can do is $a=\frac{1}{2}$, which gives a value of $\frac{1}{12}$.

Now if the minimimum is on the inside,

$$\int_0^1 \min_a\ (x-a)^2\,dx,$$

you are allowed to pick a *different $a$ for every $x$* and can do much better than the single-$a$ case. In particular, you can just pick $a=x$ for every $x$, giving the integral a value of zero.

Comment: yeah I agree that in this case you can't but in my case a is in function of x, a(x) so my intutions says that you can pick up the optimal a for each x, and that's equal to bring the min inside the integral. Isn't it?

Comment: @TommasoBendinelli Generally speaking, no, and for the same reason (you can always do at least as well picking a different function for each $x$ as picking a single function for the entire integral). If $f$ depends only on the *value* $z(x)$ and is not a functional of $z$, then it's true that
$$\min_{z:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}} \int_a^b f[x,z(x)]\,dx = \int_a^b \min_{y\in\mathbb{R}} f[x,y]\,dx,$$
which may be what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

First, the notation $ \min\limits_{z(x)}$ is very confusing and should not be used.

The minimum is defined for an object belonging to a set. You should write $\min\limits_{z \in A}$ and define what the set $A$ is.

Second in the case you describe, I imagine that the set $A$ is a set of functions. But which one? Continuous? Integrable?

Finally when everything will be properly defined, **but only then**, it is unlikely that the equality you wrote holds.

Comment: Sorry for the misleading notation. Yeah, you are right, A is a set of function integrable.